# two single dimentional array to multidimentional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
$a = Array(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)

$b = Array(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
)
```

I want to merge these arrays like,

```
$ab = Array([1] => a, [2] => b);
```

How can I do this? I have dynamic arrays.. So, It shouldn't be static merging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **PHP >= 5**

For PHP >= 5, you can use [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/array_combine) to create a new array using the keys from the first argument and the values from the second:

```
$ab = array_combine($a, $b);
```

**Note:** this function returns boolean false when the length of both arrays is not the same.

> **PHP < 5**

For older versions of PHP, a simple [`foreach`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) will do this for you:

```
$ab = array();
foreach($a as $key => $value) {
    $ab[$value] = $b[$key];
}
```

**Note:** using this technique, you can implement an option for what to do when the arrays are different sizes.

Answer (score 2):

Use PHP's built-in array_combine() function

```
$ab = array_combine($a, $b);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - have created a community wiki answer combining both methods.